# My button didnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i created a login form, but when i click on login i can't send username and password to db, with this code:

`<a id="enter" href="#"><div id = "enterbutton">enter</"div></a>`.

And i am able to send username and pass with this code:

`<input id="enterbutton" type="submit" value="Login">`

and now this button look ugly, because i have pic for this button added in my css. With this first code button look exactly how i want it to be. How to fix this?
My form look:

```
<form name="forma2" action="login.php" method="post">
        <br>
        <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="username" maxlength="18" placeholder="username">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
```

Work's but without css.

Comment: can you paste the `jQuery` code you are using

Comment: i didnt use jquery..

Comment: If you want a button as `div` you should declare the `.click()` event

Comment: you will have to use `jQuery` in order to submit the form `$("#enter").click(function(){$("form").submit();});`

Comment: the `type='submit'` is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a `button` as `div` you should declare in your JavaScript the `.click()` event how this:

```
$('#enter').on('click', function(){
  $('#form[name="forma2"]').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use:

```
<a id="enter" href="#"><div id = "enterbutton">enter</"div></a>
```

Because you have a specific css you've applied to it, then simply do.

```
$('#enter').on('click', function(){
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

Just remember to add an id to your form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use anchor to submit form but you will use event handler:

```
<form id='myForm' name="forma2" action="login.php" method="post">
    <br>
    <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="username" maxlength="18" placeholder="username">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <br>
  <a id="enter" href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("myForm").submit()'><div id = "enterbutton">enter</div></a>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <form name="forma2" action="login.php" method="post" id="myForm">
        <br>
        <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="username" maxlength="18" placeholder="username">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitMe();">Submit</a>
    </form>




    <script>
        function submitMe() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a little bit?  Tell us what you did?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Grimbode is good. But I don't like to add more script and you may not have jQuery either. We can handle it with CSS only.
The problem with your `<a>` is you didn't add any handler for this, so whenever you click on this `<a>`, it won't do anything. `<input type="submit">` is for form, it handles exactly what we want. But usually, the `input` come with some of default CSS, I don't like it, and you either.

You can find my sample for your case here:
https://jsfiddle.net/y7mvu9zn/